Programmatically set ReactGrid @silevis/reactgrid cell?
Using the following ReactGrid component, is it possible to programmatically set focus to a specific cell?
import { ReactGrid } from '@silevis/reactgrid';
Can anyone point me to documentation or provide any insight on if this is possible or not?  I have tried using javascript to set the focus, for example:
const cellElement = gridRef.current.querySelector(`[data-cell-colidx="${columnIdx + 1}"][data-cell-rowidx="${rowIdx}"]`);

if (cellElement) {
  cellElement.setAttribute('tabindex', '-1');
  cellElement.addEventListener('focus', () => console.log('Cell focused'));
  cellElement.focus();
}

and I get a console log that cell is focused, but the border highlight doesn't move to the cell I am trying to focus, and also when I start typing it still enters text into the original cell.
I appreciate any guidance and everyone who took the time to read this.
I tried the code that I entered in the details of the problem above, and I was expecting for the focus to shift to the new cell and to be able to begin typing into it.

The cell border in version 4 is set separately by an internal store, which is why you cannot achieve the desired effect. In the upcoming version 5, the cell focus will be fully controlled by the system focus.
